# sqlite3: how to detect rowid alias column (primary key)

Tags: sqlite

Using SQLite3, if you create a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
id int primary key,
--define other columns here--
)
```

it turns out `sqlite3_column_type(0)` always returns `SQLITE_NULL`.
If I [read on a bit](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid), this may well be by design because this column is actually an alias to the internal `rowid` field.

Still, what is the programatical way to determine a certain column is an/the alias to the `rowid` field?

(Perhaps related, can I use `sqlite3_column_type(x)==SQLITE_NULL` to determine if the field of the *current* record holds `NULL`?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to http://www.sqlite.org/draft/lang_createtable.html#rowid

> A PRIMARY KEY column only becomes an
>   integer primary key if the declared
>   type name is exactly "INTEGER". Other
>   integer type names like "INT" or
>   "BIGINT" or "SHORT INTEGER" or
>   "UNSIGNED INTEGER" causes the primary
>   key column to behave as an ordinary
>   table column with integer affinity and
>   a unique index, not as an alias for
>   the rowid.

So in your case it's "int" so invalid alias

Comment: tried `CREATE TABLE test (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, ...)` and that works, thanks!

Comment: @StijnSanders - did you ever find an answer to "what is the programmatic way to determine a certain column is the alias to `rowid`"?  I want to test/confirm `id integer primary key` is the same as `id integer primary key asc`

Comment: No, but looking back now, I don't think you should ever need/want to. The answer is in the source. Check what sqlite does to `integer primary key asc` with a C debugger and you will know.